# 301 redirection with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

So I've to make some 301 redirection on a website,

I've this url :

```
file.aspx?level1=Navigation+Pilot
```

I want to redirect this url to this final one :

```
/list_pilots/navigation_pilot/
```

So I wrote this rule :

```
RewriteRule ^file.aspx?level1=Navigation+Pilot /list_pilots/navigation_pilot/ [R=301,L,QSD]
```

But the final url when I test into my browser is :

```
http://www.test.com/list_pilots/navigation_pilot/?level1=Navigation+Pilot
```

How to get rid of the parameters in this url ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

QueryString is not part of match in RewriteRule's pattern. To match against querystring, you need to use a RewriteCond.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /file\.aspx\?lavel1=([^\s+]+)\+([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /list_pilots/%1_%2? [L,R]
```